# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.3

I have created GIT repo and tried but same error display

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not 
found in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\bootstrap\app.php:14 Stack trace: #0 
C:\xampp\htdocs\app\public\index.php(22): require() #1 {main} thrown in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\app\bootstrap\app.php on line 14
```

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, I didn't have the full vendor dependencies in place (composer file was messed up during original install) - so running any artisan commands caused a failure.

I was able to use the `--no-scripts` flag to prevent artisan from executing before it was included. Once my dependencies were in place, everything worked as expected.

```
composer update --no-scripts
```

Comment: Yes I have given a try but my pc compatible with laravel 5.6 project is 5.3,In that case what should I do?